# How to read a variable from another class?

Tags: java, android

Im wondering how can I read a variable from one class's to another?

I have two class's, triangle.java and screen.java

in triangle.java I have: public double bound=0;

how to I read that variable in Screen.java?

triangle.java:

```
public class triangle extends Activity
{

public EditText txtbound;
public double bound = 0;

txtbound = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtbound);

public double calculate()
{
    bound=Double.parseDouble(txtbound.getText().toString());

    // do maths here

}
}
```

and Screen.java has:

```
double bound1 = triangle.bound;
```

this doesnt work, how to I get the variable in Screen.java? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make bound1 private in Screen class like

```
private double bound1; //do not initialize fields here
```

Use getters/setters in Screen like

```
    public double getBound() {
      return bound1;
    }

    public void setBound(double bound1) {
        this.bound1 = bound1;
    }
```

In Triangle acquire instance of Screen:

```
Screen scr = new Screen();
scr.setBound(this.bound); --> this way the bound1 in Screen will have the value of bound from Triangle
```

It's a convention to name your classes starting with capital letters. 
You also don't have to initialize your class fields when declaring them. Better
use constructors for that. 
I suggest you read this [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html) to get more familiar with classes, fields and variables. Will save you time in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

do  `public static double bound=0` in triangle.java

then after importing triangle.java,
you can do  `double bound1 = triangle.bound` in screen.java or in any other something.java

Comment: and this is because then 'bound' will be a class variable rather than an instance variable, for more info read http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Answer (score 0):

You can only access an attribute of another class by creating a object of it like

```
double bound1 = new Triangle().bound;
```

Or you need to make the variable static so that the variable will not require an object instance like

```
public static double bound = 0;
```

And use like

```
double bound1 = Triangle.bound;
```

I didnt notice earlier but your class extends the activity class, in that case go with the static method. You should not create instances of activity using 'new'

To share values between activities,
You can extend the application class. And add your attributes there.
You can access the instance of the class by using this command

```
MyApplication appContext = (MyApplication)getApplicationContext();
double bound1 = appContext.bound;
```

This is a singleton so it will always return the same instance.
To make this work you need to add this to the application tag of the manifest file

```
android:name=".MyApplication"
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the value of triangle.bound without an instance of the class Triangle. But since it is an activity, you may need to make bound static.

```
public static double bound = 0;
```

but a good practice is to make bound a static variable in another class (which is not an activity) and set/get its value from there.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static double bound = 0;
}
```

And then set its value in triangle class and use it in Screen.java

Answer (score 0):

Java conventions would say that you need a getBound() method that returns the instance's value.

Using a static variable is fine-ish if it's a class-level variable and all instances can share the same value, but in this case I'd provide a normal getter, most likely.